# Jackson ObjectMapper adjusts dates to context timezone when deserializing even if explicitly disabled

Tags: java, jackson, jodatime

This is the format of the date in JSON that I want to serialize/deserialize:

> "2014-06-18T06:26:56-07:00"

The Joda DateTime field is declared as follows:

```
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    private DateTime dueTime;
```

The mapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .registerModule(new JodaModule())
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);

mapper.writeValueAsString(objectWithDT)).as("application/json")
```

In the resulting JSON the date with timezone above changes to:

```
2014-06-18T13:26:56+0000
```

Comment: The JodaModule will serialize DateTime instances into a Unix Timestamp. If I run your example, I get the following String `"1403098016000"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE) is a **deserialization** feature and it's not taken into consideration when performing **serialization**.

One possible solution is to create an `ObjectMapper` instance with a `TimeZone`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper()
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
            .registerModule(new JodaModule())
            .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-7"));
```

For more details, check the [`DateTimeSerializer`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/ser/DateTimeSerializer.java) code.